# exit function not working

Tags: python, exit

I am trying to exit the program if the value is not what I want but it doesn't do anything. What seems to be the problem? I think it stops the program but does not print "Invalid Subnet Mask".

```
from sys import exit
def maskvalidation(mask):
    string = mask.split(".")
    toInt = [int(i) for i in string]
    binary = [bin(x) for x in toInt]
    purebin = []
    for x in binary:
        purebin.append(x[2:])
    if purebin[0] == "11111111":
        print("good")
    else:
        exit("Invalid Subnet Mask")

maskvalidation("251.0.0.0")
```

Comment: are you looking for `return("Invalid Subnet Mask")`

Comment: Running your program works just fine for me.  :/

Comment: I'd like to see it printing out "Invalid Subnet Mask" and stop the program at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

help for [`sys.exit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exit)

```
    exit(...)
        exit([status])

        Exit the interpreter by raising SystemExit(status).
        If the status is omitted or None, it defaults to zero (i.e., success).
        If the status is an integer, it will be used as the system exit status.
        If it is another kind of object, it will be printed and the system
        exit status will be one (i.e., failure).
```

So it is being used correctly in the question.

Furthermore, your sample program works fine for me on linux for Python2.7 and Python3.4.

It does however send the output to `stderr` rather than `stdout`, so perhaps that is the problem you are seeing

Comment: @Jin, are you running it from a console or inside an ide or some other way? Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: I have an ide on my mac os x. I am using python 3.4.3

Comment: so I just tested on my mac using ide and linux but it's doing only half what i need it to do. - only stopping program. not printing

Comment: I just ran the program on command line using python3 filename. It worked but still don't know why it doesn't work in IDLE.

Comment: @Jin, Perhaps IDLE is only showing stdout and not stderr. As a workaround you could use a `print()` followed by `exit(1)`